# Error: "The security token included in the request is invalid" when using Boto python

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting this error when I run my django project on nginx. I use dynamodb for database and S3 for serving static files in the project. The project runs fine when operated on localhost.

The project originally was hosted in another ec2 instance where it ran like charm. I fired up a new ec2 instance from an image of that instance. And now it is throwing this error.
The thing is,

> the connection works fine when I run some test code on the command
> line.

But throws this error when the project runs.

## JSONResponseError at /

```
JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://ec2-54-200-144-115.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/?attempt=1&code=AQBfOzPR4Hlgrpkjz-qXQj8b7OLq6cm1NM_oZf64Wz3EmlX2-VDS6qfZ5V5f0Tmbx4MrLc4SGuJxUHa8drQClz3A1IWMVqUGKLEEW_0ol1RqClI8cZViWreBm5c3HJ-Vp48Xx81a7gvXSjRNJUn-kazXqahDrgsAeLez_8FrXIb_HWHyekhnUmxgkskRGBNzcTtpqASNe3agzG3ZZowCMYi6bDBAdVuODli3ApWQWENSmjLaN5QbZWbGo3ATvJNMAUQjj6VTHCkVS-UWcuh-PtwAAFtUqb8HkLsbFG31KevwPKz6x10ojD45pe03zA1SF_g
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: JSONResponseError
Exception Value:    
JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
Exception Location: /srv/www/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py in _retry_handler, line 1530
Python Executable:  /srv/www/test/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Can't understand what's going on. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check that you copied the values of the ACCESS and SECRET keys correctly? Sometimes you might mixed the two.

Comment: Yes, I checked. The thing is, the connection is fine from the console but this error occurs when I run the project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are getting this message since the security credentials / Access Keys for your AWS account has been changed.

Try again with new access keys it will work.

All the best.

Comment: It is still throwing the same error although I have recreated my access token and secret and updated the app with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a newer version of python 2.7? I had a similar error with this because of the ssl fixes.
I was doing this and it worked

```
import ssl
# for fix to python on mac which is newer than the one on linux
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score -1):

because none of the solutions worked here was the solution for me.

on a mean stack,  I had to run as sudo

```
sudo forever start startme.js
```

or

```
sudo node startme.js
```

when i did NOT use 'sudo', I received the error:

```
UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Comment: This sounds like your valid AWS credentials are only in the root user's home folder and not in your own.