# Dynamo Db JSONResponseError with boto under Flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-dynamodb, boto, aws-sdk

I have this module which connects to Dynamo, creates a session table, and puts an item in it:

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey
from boto.regioninfo import RegionInfo
from boto.dynamodb2.layer1 import DynamoDBConnection
import uuid

try:
    sessions = Table(
        table_name='IssueBoxSessions', 
        schema=[HashKey('SessionId')],
        connection=DynamoDBConnection(
        region=RegionInfo(name='eu-west-1',
                          endpoint='dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')
        ))
except:
    print("Dynamo can't connect")

def create_session():
    id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    res = sessions.put_item(data={
        'SessionId': id,
        'data': {
            'user_id': 1, 
            'ip': '10.1.1.10',
            'datetime': 'now'
        }
    })
    print(res)
    return res
```

Note that I'm developing and testing on an EC2 instance and authenticating with Dynamo using an IAM Role attached to the instance.

Because I'm using IAM, no code is needed for authentication. They allow an entity (my instance) access to certain services (dynamo). They were designed to prevent access keys having to be put in code for certain AWS resources. If it was a case of authentication, it wouldn't work in the interpreter either. I'm confident this issue is coming from something besides the IAM authentication.

So when I import this `create_session` function in the python interpreter and call it, it works:

```
>>> from issuesite.session_handler import create_session
>>> create_session()
True
True
```

But, when I try and use it anywhere near flask, it has a melt down:

```
from flask import request
from issuesite.session_handler import create_session
from issuesite import app

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    if create_session():
        return "ok"
```

The error thrown is:

```
JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
```

In fact, here's the whole traceback in all it's beauty:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/server/issuesite/views/base.py", line 14, in login
  if create_session():
File "/server/issuesite/session_handler/__init__.py", line 29, in create_session
  'datetime': 'now'
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 821, in put_item
  return item.save(overwrite=overwrite)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/items.py", line 455, in save
  returned = self.table._put_item(final_data, expects=expects)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 835, in _put_item
  self.connection.put_item(self.table_name, item_data, **kwargs)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 1510, in put_item
  body=json.dumps(params))
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2842, in make_request
  retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 954, in _mexe
  status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
File "/server/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2885, in _retry_handler
data)
```

Comment: Are you confident the system clock on the client machine is in reasonable sync?

Comment: ntpstat,
synchronised to NTP server (193.1.219.116) at stratum 2, 
time correct to within 42 ms, polling server every 1024 s, --- Yes

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted you're using regular connection methods of Boto, while you should use the ones specific for IAM (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/iam.html).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a credentials issue. Are you using the correct credentials? Looks similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060428/error-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-invalid-when-using-boto-p). It may be worth setting the [debug logger](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=set_stream_logger#troubleshooting-connections) to see from where/what credentials are being pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using actual AWS Credentials instead of an IAM Role, and in the end I taking an AMI of the instance and launching another instance from it with the same IAM Role and interestingly it had no problems talking to Dynamo.

I ended up continuing with the replacement instance.

However, I can't be sure what exactly caused the issue.